Can employers check at home whether employees are actually sick?
This relates to a recent story in the German news, (or here behind paywall) that HR personal at Tesla visited employees that called in sick at their private homes in order to check that they are actually sick.
The common rule in Germany is that an employee can call in sick for one or two days without any proof and needs a doctors note starting at day three but employers are free to request a doctors note starting day one. Either way the employee choses the doctor and the employer doesn't get to question what the doctor wrote.
So it seems to me that visiting an employee at home doesn't give the employer any useful or actionable information in any way, regardless of how sick or not sick the employee looks. It feels like harassment of the employee. Additionally while HR generally has the private addresses of employees these are not meant for this purpose so this seems to be an abuse of the information entrusted to them. So what is the general status of such check-up visits?

In 2015, the Bundesarbeitsgericht ruled on a similar scenario (summary in German here): hiring a detective to observe the sick employee can only be lawful if there are concrete facts to establish the suspicion that the sick time might be fraudulent. For example, there might be valid suspicion if the employee claims they've broken their leg, but can be seen jogging around town. Of course, employees should never disclose their diagnosis to their employer.

Btw here's an article from a public broadcaster, thus free from cookie- or pay-walls. An employment lawyer was interviewed about the Tesla incident: https://www.rbb24.de/wirtschaft/beitrag/2024/09/interview-brandenburg-tesla-krankheit-kontrollbesuche.html

The RBB text says Wenn ich das Gefühl habe, da macht jemand auf meine Kosten blau, dann würde ich den Leuten schon raten, nicht gleich zum Arbeitgeber zu gehen, sondern das unmittelbare Gespräch zu suchen. Over on workplace I keep reading the opposite advice to rely on the management

@BernhardDöbler Your quote is based on a misunderstanding whose responsibility the missing work of the sick employees is. It assumes it is the job of the healthy colleagues to make up for it. It is not, if some people are sick, less work gets done overall. Maybe some of the healthy employees should take over some tasks of the sick employees instead of their own, or do paid overtime to do both but these are management decisions.

Article of a German law-newspaper on this topic: https://www.lto.de/recht/hintergruende/h/tesla-arbeitsunfaehigkeit-mitarbeiter-krankheit-kontrolle-zuhause-arbeitgeber

france
Yes, kind-of.
Basics of sick day in France
Sick days require a doctor’s note from day one. That "doctor’s note" is a multi-part standardized document, the arrêt de travail = (notice of) work stoppage. Part of the arrêt de travail is sent to social security and part is sent to the employer.
One of the reasons for that is that social security partially idemnifies employees for sick days. "Philosophically", sick days are treated as a form of unemployment rather than a leave of absence. ("Social security" is in fact many different semi-public organisms for that purposes, and the rules for how much is indemnified when are atrociously complex, but the basic idea is that the state is not enthusiastic about paying benefits without documentation.)
As the employer does not pay a wage for sick days, it is required to keep a correct accounting of those days; monthly pay slips include that information.
In certain cases, the employer must also indemnify the employee. Which fraction of the salary, for how long, for which employees, is an atrociously complex question; but the basic idea remains that under some conditions the employer (or its insurance) acts as a "sick day insurance" regarding the employee. Under those conditions, the employer has a right to a medical contre-visite (counter-visit) to verify that the employee is in fact sick.
Conditions of the arrêt de travail and counter-visit
The modalities of the counter-visit are codified as articles R1226-10 to R1226-12 of the social security code. A 2024 decree changed formulation a bit, but the only significant update is the ability to perform the counter-visit at the doctor’s office rather than at the patient’s home.
The employer may mandate a doctor of their choice for a counter-visit.
The part of the arrêt de travail received by the employer does not specify the medical reason. However, it does specify (article R323-11-1 of the social security code) whether the employee

is not allowed to leave home at all;
is allowed to leave home, but must be there in the time slots 9-11 and 14-16
is allowed to leave home without restriction.

Case #3 is a derogatory process, which the doctor must justify to the social security by medical means. (See "in practice" below.) In such a case, the employee must inform their employer of their availability for a medical counter-visit. Hence, at any rate, the employee must be at home at certain timeslots that the employer knows, and available for a counter-visit.
The doctor who performed the counter-visit informs the employer of whether the arrêt de travail is medically justified or not; or, if the counter-visit was impossible, why it was the case (e.g. employee not present at home). If the doctor deems the arrêt de travail to be unjustified, they must write up their reasoning and send it to social security (but not to the employer, who is not allowed to know elements of a medical nature; the only thing they are supposed to know is whether the employee can work). If so, social security will usually suspend benefits; the employee may contest that decision (in which case the medical motives in the original arrêt de travail, plus the counter-visit report, form the basic paper trail).
Under no circumstances is HR allowed to perform the counter-visit themselves; it is a medical act.
Practical considerations
Picture the scene: you are at home sick. Someone knocks on your door, with no previous notice, on behalf of your employer. They ask about your health; they cannot stay long, they have many other similar visits to do. Do you trust that person to analyze your medical situation impartially and not report any confidential information to the employer?
Of course not. The first thing you tell your colleagues when you go back to work (or before, in this age of social media) is that HR sent a goon to check on you. The internal (and external) optics are terrible, as Tesla Germany is currently finding out. Ford did that a century ago, but it did not make him popular, even at a time where "employers should foster good moral habits in their employees" was politically palatable (or possibly the majority view).
A cursory online search also suggests that the counter-visit activity is mostly made by specialized farms, whose marketing materials heavily lean on "we will bust your lazy employee", at prices that suggest the medical examination is rather perfunctory (€120 per visit, including travel costs and the administrative follow-up with social security). I suspect the actual visit sounds more like "fear and awe" and less like "carefully-documented first step of a fact-intensive legal dispute".
Picture another scene: you are an HR employee at a large-ish company (100+ employees). You learn that Jane from accounting has been absent for two days. Let’s say that somehow, Jane's boss has extremely convincing evidence, obtained by no questionable means, that Jane is lying about being sick (e.g.: Jane just posted on Twitter/Mastodon "going to the beach with my gf while my stupid employer thinks I’m sick lol"). Do you arrange for a counter-visit?
Even if you wanted to, it is not even clear you materially can. Jane is coming back tomorrow; it just took time to get to you because of internal bureaucracy. Even if you can; what is the point? Firing Jane for cause does not require you to have her social security benefits cut or to put her doctor through disciplinary proceedings.
I would speculate that the counter-visit is a useful legal tool in very few cases. It is however a useful extra-legal tool; for short-term leaves, to strike fear into a misbehaving employee; for long-term leaves, to apply financial pressure on the employee to settle on a amiable separation. (You might infer that I am not a fan of the practice; you would be right.)
